# GTM event working but is not showing in Google Analytics Events, why?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to setup 1 click event to be fired in Google Analytics using the newest `dataLayer` object and have it set to be triggered like so:

```
$('.vinyl-calc .calculate').click(function() {
    // some code here...
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'calculatorClick',
        'calculatorType': 'vinyl'
    });
});
```

and

```
$('.silane-calc .calculate').click(function() {
    // some code here...
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'calculatorClick',
        'calculatorType': 'silane'
    });
});
```

I created the dataLayer variable correctly in Google Tag Manager and the tag named, "Tools and Calculators" with the custom event `calculatorType` added to it, which as shown below is being triggered via Google Tag Manager:

[image: GTM Image 1]
and
[image: GTM Image 2]

However, going into Google Analytics, even in Realtime does not show any events happening here.  I do not see anything at all in Google Analytics and can't seem to track this at all in Google Analytics.  How to get the event `calculatorClick` showing in google analytics with the `calculatorType` variable???

I have been at this for hours trying all kinds of ways to get this working and nothing is working correctly.  Some references I have followed that just do not work in Google Analytics are https://johannesmehlem.com/blog/google-analytics-event-tracking-via-google-tag-manager/#section3.4 and https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/pull-data-from-data-layer-google-tag-manager-tutorial/

1st - Why is this soo complicated?  And how to get GTM linked to GA correctly so that it is tracking events?  Because there are currently NO events in GA and I've been triggering these click events all day.

Here is the Tag and triggers in Google Tag Manager that are LIVE:
[image: All Tags in GTM]
and here is the Tools and Calculators Tag Properties.  I'm not sure what the Category, Action, Label, and/or Value properties are supposed to have in them, so I've been testing different values in here to try to get it to send to GA (which it does not).
[image: Tools and Calculators Tag Properties]

I actually have 3 triggers on this so as to be sure it is working.  I suppose I only need 1, but I wanted to be sure it was working in GTM.

I don't know where you get to the TAGS in Google Analytics however.  I don't see any option for tags anywhere in GA.  Only in GTM.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your GA tag? - the one that you want to fire on this event.

Comment: Does that help any?

Answer (score 1):

Each custom event in GA could have an `Event Category`, `Event Action`, and (optionally) an `Event Label` and `Event Value`

Now that I am not a superuser in GTM, I believe that you still need to map your data layer variables into the corresponding Google Event for that to show up properly within GA.

[Google's Custom Event documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)
[Google's GTM documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide)

---

**Updated**
GTM is just a way to help make it easier for developers to load data into GA or add custom scripts, etc. If you want to store them as GA events, you will need to understand how the GA Event works. That's why I include the Event documentation (which sadly refers to the dated ga method.) you can clearly see the `eventCategory` etc there.

1. In GTM, you will need to set up data layer variable based on the event category you have pushed through.
2. Then you create an Event and map those Event Category etc field to the corresponding datalayer variable.
3. You then need to specify a trigger so that GA knows when to fire that event.

I believe the latest method is actually using the `gtag`. The default event snippet still uses the old `ga` syntax last time I checked.

Comment: The GTM Documentation does not show anything like Event Category, Action or even a label and/or Value.  But I do notice this in the GTM Tag Editing options for Event.  But how to add these for the `dataLayer` object exactly.  But, more importantly, do they than need to be added in the GTM somehow?  NO EXAMPLES from the Google's GTM documentation even use these in the `dataLayer` object if that is what you are referring to here.  I'm trying to use the new GTM method.  Not interested in the old `ga` method of doing this, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Please see my updated response above. Thanks! BTW, I am using my 5 min coffee break to help you here; it would be nice if you are being more courteous as I am really trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here.  Lately, it's been feeling like stackoverflow is becomming a dying site anymore when it comes to asking for help.

Comment: Do I need to change the `dataLayer` object?  And if so, can you help me to understand how to change it so that I can still keep my custom event in there?

Comment: How do you want your event be logged in GA? (i.e., the eventCategory, eventAction, etc.?)

Comment: Calculator Click = silane or vinyl (those are the values of the Calculator Click event).  That is how I would like it to be logged.  But how to do this?

Comment: I don't know anything about Event Category or Event Action.  I just want the event to have 2 different values for Calculator Click event.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So, I created a dataLayer variable called, "Calculator Type" (`calculatorType`) which gets passed into the `dataLayer` object depending on which button is clicked, the value that gets passed is either silane or vinyl, and I just want to know how many people clicked on the Calculator type of silane and how many clicked on the calculator type of vinyl in Google Analytics.  I thought this is what tags are for?  But this seems too complicated using the Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Yes. The event category can be ‘calculator’ action = ‘click’ and label = vinyl or silane

Comment: In your data layer, create variable representing those values. Then create the data layer variables in GTM. Then, in your event snippet, reference those data layer variables. Then, hook the trigger to the action on which you want your events to fire

Comment: I don't see dataLayer anywhere in Google Analytics.  Where is that located?

Comment: Here is a good tutorial re: linking datalayer variables with UTM. It looks a bit dated but the concept should still hold: https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/10/15/unlock-data-layer-google-tag-manager/

Comment: this too: https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/10/03/google-tag-manager-auto-event-tracking/